# Does the latest version of Ubuntu (12.04) support Unity 3D?

Tags: 12.04

I just installed the latest version of Ubuntu (12.04) 64bit.

I am using a Radeon HD 7750 vid card. I think I have the Catalyst driver installed correctly. But when I go to system and look at the details, it shows that my graphics is VESA:01. Does this mean I it, I didn't correctly install my driver?

System Specs: **MB:** ASUS P7P55-M **CPU:** Intel i5 Quad Core **MEM:** 4GB DD3 **VC:** HIS Radeon HD 7750 (1GB DDR5)

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's the output of `fglrxinfo` when you enter it in a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)?

Answer (score 2):

this command will tell you if your display card supports 3d Unity

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```